# How to print/send to printer .ps file generated by tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

**My Code**

```
def printdata():
        try:
            canvas.postscript(file="tmp.ps",colormode='color')
            os.startfile("tmp.ps","print") #this does'nt work
            os.remove("tmp.ps")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            os.remove("tmp.ps")
```

I want to print this tmp.ps by default printer of the system. I am intending to use it on windows platform.

Comment: Convert .ps file to image file (.jpg,..) and then use `os.startfile()`

Comment: yes, I used Ghostscript with pillow module to solve this issue.

Comment: If your platform is Windows and the default printer supports postscript, then you can try executing `os.system("copy tmp.ps prn")`.

Comment: Should I make the assumption that "prn" is the name of the printer?